# Displays dates less than the current day's date

Tags: sql

In my program, I have a data grid view. I make some amounts due for payment today. I made a display of the amounts that are due and have not been paid (late) I want a code that displays the dates less than the current date of the day I tried that following code but it only fetches the lower days and does not look For the month or year if it is greater or not than the current day's date

```
        tbl = db.readData("SELECT  * from Payments  where date_batch < CONVERT(varchar(50),GetDate(), 103)", "");
        DgvSearch.DataSource = tbl;
```

The problem with the previous code is that it doesn't fetch the date lower by day, month and year.
Fetches the date less than the current date in terms of day only I want in terms of day, month and year

Comment: Instead of converting `GetDate()` to a string (life lesson: dates as strings are just asking for trouble!), convert `date_batch` to  a datetime (if it's not already).

Comment: What data type is `date_batch`? Why are you converting `GETDATE()` to a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: This appears to be more of a question about SQL than about C#. The C# stops at `db.readData(string, string)` and that first string is the SQL you're passing to... SQL Server? MySQL?. You should store dates in a field of type `date` or `datetime`, rather than `varchar`, for exactly these kinds of scenarios...

Comment: is there a solution? varchar this is my format for date record of type

Comment: That's the problem. Change it

Comment: If varchar is your format for the date column you should fix that. And I say, "fix" because the schema really is considered **broken**.

Comment: *Fetches the date less than the current date in terms of day* - because you've told the database your data is a string so it's sorting it according to string sorting rules. Store the data in a date type; it's why we have different datatypes in the first place. At the very least if you're not going to change the data type, make that date a string in yyyymmdd order (not ddmmyyyyy order) then it will sort and compare as you might expect..

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately I changed the format to 112 instead of 103

Comment: What programming language? What database?

Comment: USING  C# AND  SQL Server

Comment: *It didn't work unfortunately I changed the format to 112 instead of 103* - i think you misunderstood what I said; it's the data in the table that has to be changed; the use of CONVERT is relatively irrelevant. if your table data were in yyyyMMdd then you could just do eg `where x < '20211231'` and it would work.. but storing as dates would be easiest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm going to assume date_batch is a VARCHAR(10) or similar and contains data like:

```
28/12/2021
29/11/2021
30/08/2021
31/12/2021
```

As you can see these "strings that look like dates to a human" are in order. They are not in date order, they are in alphabetical order. Big difference - SQLServer sorts strings alphabetically. When you ask for strings "less than x" it uses alphabetical sorting rules to determine "less than"-ness

Don't stores dates in a string. SQLServer has several date specific datatypes. Use them.

The following process will dig you out of the hole you've dug yourself into:

```
ALTER TABLE Payments ADD COLUMN BatchDate DATE;

UPDATE Payments SET BatchDate = TRY_CONVERT(Date, date_batch, 103);
```

Now go look at your table and sanity check it:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE batchdate is null and date_batch is not null
```

This shows any dates that didn't convert. Correct their wonky bad data and run the update again.

Do another select, of all the data, and eyeball it; does it look sensible? Do you have any dates that have been put in as 02/03/2021 when they should have been 03/02/2021 etc

Now your table is full of nice dates, get rid of the strings;

```
ALTER TABLE Payments DROP COLUMN date_batch;
```

Maybe rename the column, but in SQLServer and c# WeCallThingsNamesLikeThis, we_dont_call_them_names_like_this

```
sp_rename 'Payments.BatchDate', 'date-batch', 'COLUMN';
```

Now you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE batchDate < GetDate()
```

And never again store dates in a string

Comment: If your dates have times, use a `datetime2(n)` datatypes, where n is the number of digits of milliseconds precision you need